# Catching "Start of scrolling" event in DataRepeater

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

I am currently looking up the way to catch the event which happens before ScrollEvent is fired in DataRepeater Control(Just only happens once, not during scrolling).

And I found no luck or clue.

Anyone knows how to do that, or any clue/suggestion/idea would be helpful.

Comment: *Before* the ScrollEvent? I think you'll probably have to override WndProc, and catch the scroll message before letting the base implementation do it's work.

Comment: Oh, or are you trying to basically add ScrollStarts and ScrollEnds type events?

Comment: @Octopoid there are no such of these ScrollStarts or ScrollEnds in Datarepeater. I hope it had, but no, poor me.

Comment: That's right, but you can make a custom extended class and *add* those events, if that's what you're trying to achieve.